# Datetime-local change from European to American date

Tags: html

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

I know it retrieves the local time from your PC, however is there a way to make display as US time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1):

---

you can use **JS** and append **UTC** to your datetime string before converting it like this example:

```
var date = new Date('1/01/2017 1:01:17 PM UTC');
date.toString() // "Sun Jun 1 2017 01:01:17 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```